# Change the same local variable data type in multiple stored procedures at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have recently changed some column data types to make the database more uniform. However I have many corresponding local variables `@x` for column `x` that was changed in many stored procedures that now do not agree, and have a length or data type mismatch with the column.

I need to make them all uniformly the same as what is in the table. Is there a way of writing a program or some looping alter statement, or a way in SQL Server to do this via the GUI? Otherwise I have to go through by hand and change 250+ stored procedures.

I have to do this for many columns and their respective local variables in the stored procedures and it amount to huge amounts of laborious work that I would rather not do.

Thanks

Comment: maybe useful: [How do I programmatically retrieve SQL Server stored procedure source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467482/how-do-i-programmatically-retrieve-sql-server-stored-procedure-source-that-is-id). Search stored procedure text: [earch-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73557/script-that-alters-all-stored-procedure-on-the-database) may help. I have not tested it, however it appears to allow you to search for specific text (such as a variable declaration) and update it with new text.

It would seem you should be able to replace say `datetime` with `varchar(255)` if necessary.